# SubmitForm when pressing Enter (To-do-list)

Tags: javascript, html

I was building a To Do List with HTML and JavaScript and now I want to add input not only with the submit button but also if i press enter anywhere on the page. I mainly wanna use javascript only to create that function, no "onclick" feature in html.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>To do app</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" id="inputField" />
        </form>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear List</button>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>

----------------------------------
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
      submitForm();
    });
    
    document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function () {
      document.getElementById("inputField").value = "";
      document.getElementById("myOl").innerHTML = "";
    });
    
    function submitForm() {
      let input = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
    
      let ol = document.createElement("ol");
      ol.setAttribute("id", "myOl");
      document.body.appendChild(ol);

      let y = document.createElement("LI");
      let t = document.createTextNode(`${input}`);
      y.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById("myOl").appendChild(y);
    
      document.getElementById("inputField").value = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) event listner with [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and check for the [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [`event.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) combination to check for enter key.

Dont forget to use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent reload of page.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
  submitForm();
});

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("inputField").value = "";
  document.getElementById("myOl").innerHTML = "";
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  const code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (e.key === 'Enter' || code == 13) {
    submitForm();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function submitForm() {
  let input = document.getElementById("inputField").value;

  let ol = document.createElement("ol");
  ol.setAttribute("id", "myOl");
  document.body.appendChild(ol);

  let y = document.createElement("LI");
  let t = document.createTextNode(`${input}`);
  y.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("myOl").appendChild(y);

  document.getElementById("inputField").value = "";
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" id="inputField" />
</form>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="clear">Clear List</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: this works.thanks alot! if you have any feedback on the code itself, feel free to add it.

Comment: @hashprophet Please approve this answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: cant approve yet i have to post more

Comment: Cool!! You can do it later

Answer (score 1):

You can use key up event.

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', keypress);
function keypress(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        submitForm();
    }
}
```

added e.preventDefault() to avoid form submission

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event

Comment: you also need `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default behavior of form submission by enter key

Comment: Thanks @S.Serpooshan I edited my answer

Comment: thanks @s_frix! the preventDefault() must be after the submitForm(); and also using keypress works but not keyup, not entirely sure why though.. 
document.addEventListener("keypress", keypress);
function keypress(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    submitForm();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}